# jquery library needs to be loaded just before the script and conflicts with another library

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I can't figure out how to use both javascript codes on the same page.

```
<script id="script" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#menuzord").menuzord({
            align: "right",
            effect: "slide",
            animation: "stretch"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm using this code for the menu resize in the header on every page. It is working normally but when I'm using also the endless_pagination (django) javascript this code stops working.

```
{% block js %}
     {{ block.super }}
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script src="/static/endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>

     <script>
        $.endlessPaginate({
            paginateOnScroll: true,
            paginateOnScrollMargin: 20
        });
     </script>
{% endblock %}
```

if I delete the library () than the resizing works but the endless_pagination does not. If I leave the library there than pagination is loading but not the resizing. Also if I load the library from the  the pagination is not working, it has to be loaded just before the endless-pagination.js. How can this be resolved so that both scripts are working on the same page?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: Does django include it's own version of jQuery? that would be a very likely cause. Also, be sure not to use `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` in production code please..

Comment: if I inspect element: 
127.0.0.1/:126 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
127.0.0.1/:144 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/auth-buttons.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND).. currently pagination is working because the library is present

Comment: remove jquery-latest, and use `jQuery` in place of `$`

Comment: I'm using javascript as per the official tutorial for pagination (https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html)

Comment: Right, but docs don't always provide best practices for a production environment nor do they show you how to implement the code into an existing system. You already have jQuery included, so including it twice is of course going to cause conflicts.

Comment: Kevin B thanks, your solution is working. I removed the library and used jQuery in place of $. Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Probably something in your code is interfering with the execution of your

```
jQuery(document).ready()
```

block.

Keep in mind that this code only will execute after the rest of the whole page finish loading (and in the case of the rest of the javascript in your page) and executing.

So check javascript console for any error on your pagination code. Probably something there is breaking javascript execution before menu redimension can even start executing.